# Should I use static variables in my functions to prevent recomputing values?

Tags: c++, performance, variable-declaration, member-functions

I've been writing C++ code for a while now, but there's something I've been wondering for some time, without being to find a clear answer.

My point here is the following: let's say I have a function (could be a method, could be `static`, but not necessarily), and that function uses some "heavy" object(s) (such as a string that can't be determined *easily* at compile time, but that is constant throughout the execution). An example I've actually come across is the following:

```cpp
/* Returns an endpoint for an API
 * Based on the main API URL (getApiUrl())
 */
virtual QString getEndPointUrl() const override
{
    QString baseUrl = getApiUrl();
    QString endpointUrl = QString("%1/%2").arg(baseUrl, "endpoint");
    return endpointUrl;
}
```

It's of course just an example (I know that `QString`s have their own fancy Qt memory management features, but let's admit we're dealing with basic objects).

Is it a good idea to do the following?

```cpp
virtual QString getEndPointUrl() const override
{
    /* We determine baseUrl only once */
    static const QString baseUrl = getApiUrl();
    /* We compute endpointUrl only once */
    static const QString endpointUrl = QString("%1/%2").arg(baseUrl, "endpoint");
    return endpointUrl;
}
```

As you may have guessed, the idea here is to not determine the URL at every execution of `getEndPointUrl`.

The only drawback I've found is the higher memory usage (since the objects are built the first time the function is called and destroyed only when the program ends).

Another thing is that it's considered a "better" practice to have stateless functions, but I don't really think this kind of behaviour can be qualified as a "state".

EDIT: I just wanted to point out that the values I compute are meaningless outside of the function, otherwise they could be a field of the enclosing class or whatever, but they're never used anywhere else.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: If it is not a static function, I would compute the value in Constructor. Maybe it is used later in another function.

Comment: I would agree that this does not qualify as "state", and I also think it's perfectly fine, but I have a feeling that this will get closed as "mostly opinion-based".

Comment: Your virtual function is declared in a class, isn't it? And the endpointUrl is used wherever you call the function. It would make sense to store the endpointUrl in the class where your virtual function is. I would not use a static variable. It just doesn't make sense to keep it until the program ends imo.

Comment: @MFnx I would assume that the point of making the function virtual is being able to override it (and possibly making the result more dynamic) in a derived class. You can't do that with a member variable.

Comment: @molbdnilo - you wouldn't be able to do that with a static either.    Overriding virtual functions is about changing behaviour of a call of that function, based on the actual type of object.    Using member variables of a class is not necessarily relevant to that.

Comment: May I ask why this function is virtual? Can't see the point of it...

Comment: @MFnx The function is virtual because I have helper classes to make API calls, they all derive from one which has an abstract `getEndPointUrl()`

Comment: @Thomas oh ok, I guess the function above overrides that abstract function (you could add override).

Comment: Yes you're right, I usually do, but since it wasn't a copy and paste I forgot about that. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, absolutely!

As ever, there is a trade-off, which you've already identified.

But this is a completely normal and sensible thing to do. If you don't need to compute these values every time, then don't.

In this particular case, I'd probably make these items static members of the encapsulating class, unless you have a strong need to delay instantiation (perhaps the functions are not invoked on every run and you deem these initialisations too "heavy" to perform when you don't need them).

In fact, that would render the entire function `getEndPointUrl()` obsolete. Just have it be a public member constant! Your rationale that the constant "is not used anywhere else" is a bit of a circular argument; you use the data wherever `getEndPointUrl()` is used.

Comment: Why static member instead of a normal member? To avoid reconstruction when you create another instance of the class?

Comment: @MFnx Why non-static member instead of a static member? It does not hold any instance-specific state, does it?

Comment: just to make sure it does not exist forever... unless it has real benefits (which we do not know), I would prefer a const (private) member.

Comment: The reason for having it as a function rather than a member is because my class derives from a more general class, and each "sister" class has a different implementation of `getEndPointUrl`. Is *is* common to all instances though.

Comment: @ThomasKowalski Fair enough leave it as a function then - would still probably recommend `static const` members to provide the actual data, but it doesn't really matter either way

Comment: @MFnx I consider that an abuse of members. A `const` member whose initialisation does not come from construction arguments is usually wrong :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for that one: "A const member whose initialisation does not come from construction arguments is usually wrong" This could be written in a book. I will and everybody should keep that in mind when designing their next classes.

Comment: @florgeng Worth noting that this is just my opinion

Answer (score 4):

That seems like a viable option.  I have one suggested change for your sample, and that is to call `getApiUrl()` within the second static's initializer, making it the only initializer... thusly:

```
static const QString endpointUrl = QString("%1/%2").arg(getApiUrl(), "endpoint");
```

That's one less object to keep around for the lifetime of your program.

There are a number of concerns when caching with statics:

1. You lose control over when that object's lifetime ends.  This may or may not be a problem depending on whether or not that object needs a pointer/reference to something else in order to properly clean up after itself.
2. I don't believe there are any guarantees about static object deconstruction order... It may be necessary to further wrap things in `shared_ptr` to ensure resources aren't yanked out from under your static objects.
3. Caches in general often provide a way to flush out their stored values and be repopulated.  No such mechanism exists for statics, particularly `const static`s.

EDIT:  Rumor has it that thread safety is not a concern.

But if none of those concerns apply in your particular use case, then by all means, use `static`.

EDIT: Non-trivial comment reply:

I cannot advise strongly enough against depending on static object destruction order.

Imaging changing your program such that your resource loading system now starts before your logging system.  You set a break point and step through the new code, whereupon you see that everything is fine.  You end the debug session, run your unit tests, and they all pass.  Check in the source, and the nightly integration tests fail... *if you're lucky*.  If you're not, your program starts to crash on exit in front of customers.

It turns out your resource system tries to log something on shut down.  Boom.   But hey... everything still runs fine!  Why bother fixing it, right?

Oh, and it turns out that thing your resource system was trying to log was an error condition that will only be a problem... for your biggest customer.

Ouch.

Don't be that guy.  Don't depend on static destructor order.

(Okay, now imagine that the order of object construction/destruction isn't deterministic because some of those functions with static objects are called from different threads.  Having nightmares yet?)

Comment: _"I believe there are also some thread safety concerns with static initialization"_ Not really; static init is thread-safe.

Comment: The destruction order of static objects is well-defined - it's the opposite of their construction order. Of course, you don't really know what their construction order was, so...

Comment: @molbdnilo Is that true for function-statics? Seems like it would actually be hard to accomplish since you don't know construction order until runtime.

Comment: Huh, seems it is. So there's a sort of runtime sequencing. Magic.

Answer (score 2):

## For your specific example

In your example caching will make basically no performance difference, so using `static` is probably the only method that's worth it's effort.

If your calculation was actually expensive, here are some thoughts on this way of caching in general:

## In General

### Pros:

- It's automatically thread-safe
- It's very easy to use

### Cons:

- Maintenence

  1. Effectively a singleton [with all of it's problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)

  - Might become a surprising bug if suddenly `getUrl()` needs to return different values
  - Not great for unit tests
  - etc.

  2. A lot of people don't know what the static keyword does
  3. (If you link against a static lib from multiple dynamic libraries, you will get multiple instances of the variable. Probably a [ODR violation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule))
- Function

  - Maybe it is undesired for the first call to the function to take longer
- Structural

  - Likely use after free if the cached object references something on the stack.

^ (Note that a lot of these don't apply in a certain circumstances)

### Alternatives

In order of preference:

1. Cache the value whenever the value of getUrl() is set/changed.
2. Cache the value in the object
3. Use a cache (some `map<string, shared_ptr<void>>` or something) that you [inject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (Overkill for this)

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. Actually, one of the cons you cited (`getUrl` needing to return different values) has happened to me on this exact project and it's been surprisingly hard to debug. Guess I won't make the mistake twice but still that's something to take in account.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your context.  As you rightly point out you're trading memory usage for speed.  So what's more important (if either even) in your context?  Are you on the hot path of a low latency program? Are you on a low memory device?

Comment: Neither actually, it was more of a theoretical "what if I were in a low latency programme" question

Comment: @ThomasKowalski Then go for it! Not doing so would be premature pessimization.